# Google Maps: Can't add marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can't get a marker added, probably something very simple but I'm new to this. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function addMarker() {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),

                title:"Hello World!"
            });
        }


        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        $(document).ready(function() {
            addMarker();
        })

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues, you need to set the map variable of the marker.  Your map variable is local to the initialize function.

- call the addMarker function from your initialize function (where the map exists), after the map is initialized.

  ```
      function addMarker(map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          map:map,

          title:"Hello World!"
        });
      }

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
        addMarker(map);
      }
  ```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_SO_Marker.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set map property in marker constructor or invoke setMap on a new object:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            map: map,   //make your map object global!
            title:"Hello World!"
        });
```

or

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

EDIT:
my comment about making map object global was apparently overlooked, so here it is:

map object is supposed to be global, not only for the sake of this solution, but you are going to need it in multiple functions in your script

Comment: In the docs i read it says: map (optional) specifies the Map object on which to place the marker so i'm a little confused.

Comment: The map variable is not in scope.

Comment: @geocodezip I suggested it next to map property, I should have emphasized it more

Comment: @user990717 this is optional in the constructor argument object, you can set it later using mentioned function

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't (and didn't) see any comment about the map variable needing to be global (except for your "EDIT").  It doesn't _have_ to be global, it certainly makes a lot of things simpler if it is.

Comment: it's in the code snippet, but nevermind, also I never said it has to be global, but it's just the best way to do it