# What code should I add to show location with red icon in google map?

Tags: html, google-maps

I have included google map in my html(web page), but its not showing the location with red icon(image attached). What code am I missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #CCC;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          center: {lat: 19.1738076 , lng: 72.8650819 },
          zoom: 14
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: image generated not showing red icon for location]

[image: red icon it should show]

Comment: It's called a [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps: Can't add marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413136/google-maps-cant-add-marker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define a position/marker, only the center of the map. To set a marker you need to add it to your map.

This is from the google maps api documentation on how to add a a marker:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

```
// Define position for your marker
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

// Add marker to your map
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Text for your marker!'
  });
```